GCP Cloud Function IAM Permission Denied for Vertex AI Multimodal Embedding
I am currently working with Google Cloud Platform (GCP) and encountered an issue while setting up a trigger in Cloud Functions. My goal is to create a trigger that automatically runs whenever an image is saved in a bucket. This trigger is intended to generate embeddings for the saved image using Vertex AI multimodal embedding. Despite assigning all the necessary roles and permissions to the service account, I am still receiving an IAM_Permission_Denied error when attempting to create the embeddings with the model.
process_imageq8fn6qnyyd4j Error in get_image_embedding: 403 Permission 'aiplatform.endpoints.predict' denied on resource '//aiplatform.googleapis.com/projects/snipit-db/locations/us-central1/publishers/google/models/multimodalembedding@001' (or it may not exist). [reason: "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED"

What I've done so far:
Assigned the following roles to the service account:

roles/aiplatform.user
roles/storage.objectViewer
roles/storage.objectAdmin
Verified that the service account is correctly set up in the Cloud Function.
Checked the IAM policies for the project and ensured the service account has the necessary permissions.

Steps to reproduce:

Set up a Cloud Function with a trigger for Google Cloud Storage.
Assign the service account with the necessary roles.
Attempt to use Vertex AI multimodal embedding on an image upload.


What service account do you have attached at the Cloud Function?
Is this a gen2 or gen1 Cloud Function?
Have you tried to re deploy the CF after updating the permissions?
